# Is the image of a polyhedral set under a linear function is polyhedral?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $T: X \to Y$ be a continuous linear transformation between the normed spaces $X$ and $Y$ with $\dim Y < \infty $.  Let $P \subset X $ be a polyhedral convex set. Then my question is

Is $T(P)$ a closed set in $Y$ ?

Note that a polyhedral set has the form  $P =\{ x \in X ~|~  \langle a^*_i \; , \; x \rangle \leq b_i ~~~ i =1,2,..,m \}.$

I know that if $X$ id finite-dimensional space then $T(P)$ is a polyhedral set so is closed. I'm not sure same result is true any normed spaces.

Comment: What is your definition of 'polyhedral set' in infinite dimensional spaces?

Comment: @gerw I just edited it to clarify the definition.

Comment: In general, even $T(X)$ might not be closed in $Y$.

Comment: @gerw  Thank You. you are indeed right. What about the case when $Y$  is finite-dimensional space.

I also edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Can you recall a definition of a dimension of a linear transformation?

Comment: @AlexRavsky No I'm not aware of that

Comment: Did you mean dim Y $< \infty$?

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli Yes. Thank you for catch